# Rails custom css links are not working - following tutorial in http://ruby.railstutorial.org

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, stylesheet

I'm new to rails and working my way into the tutorial here: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

I've added the blueprint css package to the public/stylesheets directory and added a custom.css file however I cannot seem to get the stylesheet to load. From my understanding fo the setup the page should have a blue background and some other small changes.

In my app/views/layouts/application.html.erb file I've added the following line:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'stylesheets/custom', :media => 'screen' %>
```

Which I believe should cause the css from the /public/custom.css to load.

In the tutorial the content of the custom.css file is located in section 5.1.2 (sorry I'm only able to post 2 hyperlinks here)
.
And the content of the app/views/layouts/application.html.erb file is here:

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#sec:adding_to_the_layout

When I view source on the page there is a link to the custom.css file here:

But clicking that brings up a "Routing Error - No route matches "/stylesheets/stylesheets/custom.css"" message.

As far as I can find I've followed the tutorial exactly so I'm not sure what is wrong or what I've missed. Any help on where to go from here would be appreciated.

complete text of the application.html.erb file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
       <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->    
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/screen', :media => 'screen' %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/print',  :media => 'print' %>
    <!--[if lt IE 8]><%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/ie' %><![endif]-->
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'custom', :media => 'screen' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <header>
        <%= image_tag("logo.png", :alt => "Sample App", :class => "round") %>
        <nav class="round">
          <ul>
            <li><%= link_to "Home", '#' %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Help", '#' %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign in", '#' %></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
      <section class="round">
        <%= yield %>
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

This still has the same error when clicking the custom.css link in source as before:

```
"Routing Error - No route matches "/stylesheets/stylesheets/custom.css""
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

is this happening on localhost or production environment? If it's production then open config/production.rb and change:

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

to

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

If this is happening in development environment then I'm wondering if you possibly have more than 1 layout file. Check to make sure you don't have application.html.erb **and** application.html.haml. It's also possible that you have a separate layout for your posts, which would be titled post.html.haml or something...

ALSO

you state the following:

```
Which I believe should cause the css from the /public/custom.css to load.
```

If your custom.css file is located in public/custom.css then it is in the wrong place, it should be in public/stylesheets/custom.css

EDIT:

below is a screenshot of your app as it appears on my machine, it looks like it works ok after moving stylesheet into the right folder. I also took the liberty of deleting `public/index.html`, but you can leave it in for now until the tutorial advises you to take it out

[image]

Comment: This is happening on localhost. I've searched and can't find any .haml files in any directory (I'm really just beginning with this - should I have those?). Also that was a misstype when i said it was in the /public directory - it is in the public/stylesheets directory.

Comment: I've also just now tried changing to: "config.serve_static_assets = true" - this did not make a difference (from your comment I didn't expect it to, but thought it worth a test).

Comment: ha, no problem. Don't worry about not having any haml files. You don't need them. Are you using the Compass gem? It normally spits your compiled CSS files into `public/stylesheets/compiled` folder. Dunno if that's an issue here... Is your custom.css file present in the right directory of your app, i.e. `public/stylesheets`

Comment: No I'm not suing the compass gem - I'm realy trying to stick with the book b/c I thought that would be a goodway to learn, but now I've spent nearly a day trying to figure out something that seems to be a lot of hassle for what at first seemed to be a small issue.

Comment: Another issue could concern the version of rails you are using here. If you are on rails 3.1, then it will expect your stylesheets to be in `app/stylesheets` (see chapter 13). What version do you have listed in your Gemfile?

Comment: I'm using rails 3.09 and the file is in the public/stylesheets directory. There isn't an app/stylesheets folder...

Comment: Totally bizarre. Do you know how to put your code on github? I'm sure we'll get to the bottom of it if some of us can clone it from there...

Comment: Well this is probably going to be embarrassing for someone to actually look at my first so far failed attempt :) but here is the github link: https://github.com/mattarse/sample_app4

Comment: from reading your code, your custom.css file is definitely in the wrong directory. You currently have it in the `public` folder. Just move it to `public/stylesheets` and it will start working :)

Answer (score 3):

Change it to `stylesheet_link_tag 'custom', :media => 'screen'`. It will automatically look in the /public/stylesheets/

Comment: It's still not working,I've added complete text of the application.html.erb file to the original post

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not sure if you ever figured this out (I'm sure you did), but I just had the same issue, and found a solution. It looks like rails is looking in /app/assets/stylesheets instead of /public/stylesheets. I'm not sure if this is the correct way it should be working, but I moved my custom.css file there and everything is now working fine.

Comment: I think this would work, but for the purposes of the tutorial, how do you make the application look for the stylesheet in /public/stylesheets, as the book/tutorial suggests it should do?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem following the tutorial but it hit me in chapter 4 where we first include the helper for the blueprint css files. I am using Rails v. 3.1.3, and for me nnaficy's answer solved the problem. Heres the description of why this is happening from the rubyonrails guide :

(source: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

"**3.1.2 Linking to JavaScript Files with the javascript_include_tag**

The javascript_include_tag helper returns an HTML script tag for each source provided.

If you are using Rails with the Asset Pipeline enabled, this helper will generate a link to /assets/javascripts/ rather than public/javascripts which was used in earlier versions of Rails. This link is then served by the Sprockets gem, which was introduced in Rails 3.1."

(i copied the above for the explanation, but specific to css is the following snippet:)

"**3.1.3 Linking to CSS Files with the stylesheet_link_tag**

The stylesheet_link_tag helper returns an HTML  tag for each source provided.

If you are using Rails with the “Asset Pipeline” enabled, this helper will generate a link to /assets/stylesheets/. This link is then processed by the Sprockets gem. A stylesheet file can be stored in one of three locations: app/assets, lib/assets or vendor/assets."

so instead of copying my blueprint folder to public/stylesheets/, i copied it to app/assets/stylesheets/ and the css did its magic.

Comment: well not so fast, now i'm in the same boat as :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738045/issue-loading-rails-3-server-after-coming-back-from-3-1

and so i dug deeper..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778586/css-files-not-being-read-in-rails-3-1

and the response from Mr. Hartl himself is DON'T USE RAILS 3.1.x!! He suggests to use 3.0.11. 

So the answer to this question for 3.1.x users is to either use the 3.0.11 with that guide, or use 3.2 and use the 2nd edition of the book.

Comment: well the good news is i don't think you have to start over again if you want to keep going with 3.1.3. i just deleted the references to blueprint and the blueprint folder itself from the app/assests/stylesheets folder, and then created a custom.css file and included it   <%= stylesheet_link_tag '/stylesheets/custom', :media => 'screen' %> in application.html.erb instead. it was a simple file, i just made the body background red to test, and sure enough it works out fine. it may be prudent to start over while its still early in case a bigger issue comes up later. however, i will be pressing on.

Comment: i pressed on to chapter 5 and found the culprit. its the ie.css files that seem to be messing things up!! i am using safari but apparently this is still where the issue comes from. i deleted the ie.css file from /blueprint/ and also the one hiding in /blueprint/src and everything seems to look as it should. too bad for the IE users that look at my page locally.. oh right thats nobody :)

Comment: nope that doesnt seem to fix it permanently.. i just cant get the blueprint to cooperate with rails.. im going to proceed with my own css instead, and do this tutorial again with rails 3.0.11 afterwards

Answer (score 1):

Change the line:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag '/stylesheets/application', :media => 'screen' %>
```

to

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag '/stylesheets/custom', :media => 'screen' %>
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Also, for those who are still working on the problem, check that you are puting the CSS in the right project. I had a folder called "sample_app" in which I started the tutorial. Some days after, I started using Aptana/RadRails, which created a custom project folder (workspace). I didn't realized and put all my css in my initial "sample_app" folder. That's why Rails could not find the css/logo!

Answer (score 0):

Same question with my current Rails 3.2.6 app. I've solved it with this include function:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag '/stylesheets/custom', :media => 'screen' %>
```

You have to use absolute path's instead of relative ones.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so maybe someone out there is still struggling, I've been trying to figure these out for a while now and i have solved the problem. Like @shime is saying Rails looks in public/stylesheets.

```
application.html.erb
-----------------
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
        <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag **'screen'**, :media => 'screen' %>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag **'print'**, :media => 'print'   %>
  </head>
    <body>
     <%= yield %>
    </body>
</html>`
```

Move **screen.css** and **print.css** from stylesheet/blueprint to **app/assets/stylesheets**.