# css files not being read in rails 3.1

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

i'm following along with the hartl tutorial. section 4.1.2, css formatting does not appear in my views. i've stored css files in `public/stylesheets/blueprint`. `application.html.erb` edited as follows:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/screen', :media => 'screen' %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/print',  :media => 'print' %>
```

in particular, the css has body font set as sans-serif,

```
font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

but i'm still getting a serif fonts in the body.

Comment: If you just want to get your app running while you figure out how the new asset pipeline engine works you can add the below line to your application.rb and your current code should work.

    config.assets.enabled = false

Answer (score 0):

Starting with rails 3.1, it will look for css from app/assets/stylesheets

so in your case put them app/assets/stylesheets/blueprint

Read about asset pipeline http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using Rails 3.1. I recommend using the exact version of Rails used in the tutorial (Rails 3.0.11 as of this writing) in order to avoid incompatibilities of this sort.

Answer (score 0):

the others are right (another comment here and several other questions elsewhere) on putting the files in app/assets/stylesheets instead of public/, but you may also have to delete the ie.css files from /blueprint/ and /blueprint/src for things to show up correctly (at least that was the case with me using safari to look at it on localhost)

Comment: nope that doesnt seem to fix it permanently.. i just cant get the blueprint to cooperate with rails.. im going to proceed with my own css instead, and do this tutorial again with rails 3.0.11 afterwards