# Issue loading rails 3 (server) after coming back from 3.1

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3

total noob to rails and am using the Hartl tutorial.

Got to chapter 4 (CSS, 4.1.2), everything seemed dandy, and ran into an issue getting

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/screen', :media => 'screen' %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/print',  :media => 'print' %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

to make the text on the page look 'prettier'. As Hartl describes it, 
'By the way, with the new stylesheets the site doesn’t look much different than before, but it’s a start'

I do agree it looks cooler and this step is obviously more than necessary to continue.

So, nothing was changing on the localhost:3000/pages/home as it looked in chapter 3.

This is what it SHOULD look like

```
http://ruby.railstutorial.org/images/figures/home_with_stylesheet.png
```

(see attached pic^)

So I finally moved the stylesheets folder from public into app/assets/stylesheets, and added

this

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application.css' %>
```

to the application.html.erb file in app/views/layouts folder
Which I found from this portion of stackoverflow :) very helpful

So I fired up localhost:3000/pages/home and everything looked as it should (in relation to the png pic posted above) but all the text was centered, and it should be on the left side.

And, in addition, I was getting this message, repeated, in the terminal:

```
Started GET "/assets/stylesheets/src/typography.css?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-01-04 17:34:13     -0800
Served asset /stylesheets/src/typography.css - 304 Not Modified (3ms)
[2012-01-04 17:34:13] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-    length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

So a buddy said it had to do with the rails version. We did share screen skype and he said in the home directory it should be 3.1 and in the sample_app directory it should be version 3.0.11 (he's a bit of a noob too but everything is going smoothly for him)

So alas I am back to getting the damn rails server to work. I'm on Snow Leopard and changed the sqlite3 thing, did bundle update then bundle install and worked fine. Now 'rails s' will not work ;/

the error message in the terminal is this:

```
/Users/davidpardy/rails_projects/sample_app/config/application.rb:8:in `require': no such file     to load -- sprockets/railtie (LoadError)
    from /Users/davidpardy/rails_projects/sample_app/config/application.rb:8:in '<top         (required)>'
    from /Users/davidpardy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails    /commands.rb:28:in `require'
    from /Users/davidpardy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:28:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/davidpardy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
    from /Users/davidpardy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.0.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

So now I'm stuck and really don't know what to do. Don't want to start from scratch.

Like I said I'm new to this so any input would be appreciated. This seems like a rather easy fix, just lost.

Comment: You should look into the rails 3.1 asset pipeline. Its kinda complicated at first, but it will help you understand how it serves assets. Great tutorial here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: Ok I appreciate that but, doesn't really seem to be the root of the problem? I mean I'm basically back to rails 3.0.11 now...not sure if that's good or bad but I've seen many comments saying 3.0.11 is more stable. And also I have heard from others pipeline is very good. But...rails s...work gosh darnit!

Comment: Can you post what your application.rb looks like?

Comment: require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
    require "active_record/railtie"
    require "action_controller/railtie"
    require "action_mailer/railtie"
    require "active_resource/railtie"
    require "sprockets/railtie"
    if defined?(Bundler)
          Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development       test)))
     end
    module SampleApp
      class Application < Rails::Application
           config.encoding = "utf-8"   
        config.filter_parameters += [:password]
        config.assets.enabled = true
        config.assets.version = '1.0'
      end
    end

Comment: Tried to post it correctly...want to email me or something? davidpardy@live.com

Comment: `require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)`
`require "active_record/railtie"`
`require "action_controller/railtie"`
`require "action_mailer/railtie"`
`require "active_resource/railtie"`
`require "sprockets/railtie"`
if defined?(Bundler)
  `Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))`
 `end`
`module SampleApp`
  `class Application < Rails::Application`
       `config.encoding = "utf-8"`   
    `config.filter_parameters += [:password]`
    `config.assets.enabled = true`
    `config.assets.version = '1.0'`
  `end`
`end`

Comment: @Spencer that is a little better I suppose, was running out of room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im in the same boat as you, i am running rails 3.1.3 and am not in the mood atm to start over for a lower rails (or to figure out how to seamlessly change rails version).

i decided to remove the blueprint folder and its two including lines in application.html.erb, and make a new inclusion of a custom css file i put directly in app/assets/stylesheets. the css was just to make the background red, and thats what it did. not sure why our pages were being centered like that using the blueprint, but it looks okay now. as mentioned earlier, the safest bet is to just use the same versions as the tutorials, or 3.0.11 for rails as mr. hartl has indicated in a comment.

Comment: as another caveat to pressing on, the server messages are still there, so the chances are there may be more issues later. but im curious and plan to redo this tutorial after i complete it this way for the sake of deeper understanding, so im still going to press on. good luck to you!

Comment: i got it to work properly by deleting the ie.css files from /blueprint/ and /blueprint/src/ . things now seem to be working fine for me running safari.

Comment: nope that doesnt seem to fix it permanently.. i just cant get the blueprint to cooperate with rails.. im going to proceed with my own css instead, and do this tutorial again with rails 3.0.11 afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Per the answer to [Trouble loading Rails Server (3.0.11, ruby 1.9.2), no such file to load -- sprockets/railtie (LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8739080/trouble-loading-rails-server-3-0-11-ruby-1-9-2-no-such-file-to-load-sproc), you should remote Rails 3.1-specific lines from auto-generated files, mostly in `config/`.

One way to figure out what lines to remove is to compare your app to a fresh Rails 3.0 app using `diff -r`

**Step 1: Create a clean Rails 3.0 app**

```
$ rails --version
Rails 3.0.10

$ rails new fresh_app
      create  
      create  README
      create  Rakefile
```

**Step 2: Use `diff -r` to compare the directories**

```
$ diff -r hartl_tutorial/config fresh_app/config
diff -r hartl_tutorial/config/application.rb fresh_app/config/application.rb
5,10c5,7
< if defined?(Bundler)
<   # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
<   Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
<   # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
<   # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
< end
---
> # If you have a Gemfile, require the gems listed there, including any gems
> # you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
> Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)
```

In case you don't know how to read a diff, the basic idea is that lines starting with < are from one file while lines starting with > are from the other file.